# Async TaskUI Update

Tags: java, android, multithreading, download, android-asynctask

I've got a file download application which I need to update progress using Asnc Task method
The progress will be displayed by Dialog and Notification Bar simultaneously, just like the sample in  the Google PLay

When I run the method , Notification Bar shows extremely slow response.
IN the ONProgressUpdate, I only update two UI progress without synchornization.

When I use thread sleep to slow down the process, it runs smoothly but the download speed is very low.

How can we ensure two UI threads running smoothly while maintaining acceptably fast downloading speed?

this is the Code

Please answer :)

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    if (values.length>0) {
        //Log.d("Download Activity", "progressUpdate:"+values[0]);
        if (values[0] < 0) {
            this.cancel(true);
            showNetworkErrorDialog();
        } else {
            //size += values[0];
            //Log.d("Download Activity", "download size:"+size);
            //downloadedGoodListSize += values[0];
            //downloadProgressBar.incrementProgressBy(values[0]);
            setCurrentProgress(values[0]);
            downloadProgressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
            double currentProg = downloadProgressBar.getProgress()*1.0/downloadProgressBar.getMax()*100;
            //progressTextView.setText( decimalFormat.format(downloadedGoodListSize*1.0/downloadProgressBar.getMax()*100.0)+"%");
            progressTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(downloadProgressBar.getProgress()*1.0/downloadProgressBar.getMax()*100)+"%");


            notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pb, 100, (int)currentProg, false);

            nm.notify(notificationID, notification);

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    Log.i("Download Activity", "onPostExecute: starting");
    downloadProgressBar.setProgress(downloadProgressBar.getMax());
    progressTextView.setText(100+"%");
    wheelProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    downloadingTextView.setText(getFinishedText());

   notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pb, 100, 100, false);
   nm.notify(notificationID, notification);
   nm.cancelAll();

    Log.i("Download Activity", "onPostExecute: set interface ok");
    finishDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: Post some code, it's hard to suggest solutions without seeing where the problem might lie.

Comment: you have to post your code in Question page not in answere's remove below one ....

Comment: Sorry I will take extra notice on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is my code

```
@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        if (values.length>0) {
            //Log.d("Download Activity", "progressUpdate:"+values[0]);
            if (values[0] < 0) {
                this.cancel(true);
                showNetworkErrorDialog();
            } else {
                //size += values[0];
                //Log.d("Download Activity", "download size:"+size);
                //downloadedGoodListSize += values[0];
                //downloadProgressBar.incrementProgressBy(values[0]);
                setCurrentProgress(values[0]);
                downloadProgressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
                double currentProg = downloadProgressBar.getProgress()*1.0/downloadProgressBar.getMax()*100;
                //progressTextView.setText( decimalFormat.format(downloadedGoodListSize*1.0/downloadProgressBar.getMax()*100.0)+"%");
                progressTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(downloadProgressBar.getProgress()*1.0/downloadProgressBar.getMax()*100)+"%");


                notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pb, 100, (int)currentProg, false);

                nm.notify(notificationID, notification);

            }
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        Log.i("Download Activity", "onPostExecute: starting");
        downloadProgressBar.setProgress(downloadProgressBar.getMax());
        progressTextView.setText(100+"%");
        wheelProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        downloadingTextView.setText(getFinishedText());

       notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pb, 100, 100, false);
       nm.notify(notificationID, notification);
       nm.cancelAll();

        Log.i("Download Activity", "onPostExecute: set interface ok");
        finishDialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: do not post your code as a `Answer` post it in your original question. you will see a link `edit` under your question post your code their..

Answer (score 1):

you are updating the notification bar, very frequently, hence the slow response. Update it once in 2-3 seconds and you will be fine.

Comment: Is it to reduce frequency of makeing updates for the progress which is set in the doInBackground ?

Comment: yes, that makes the notification bar 'too-busy' to be interacted with

Comment: To be explict , is it appropriate to set a calendar instance and limiting the timing interval to reduce the frency of updating the task ?

Comment: I have solved this
set a new timer task  and implement progress bar notification update in run method and then set a new timer to schedule the aforementioned timer task with fixed delay and period.